# Incoming SMS filtered into a specified user

Tags: sms

My work uses a system that pages me with SMS messages. Cool? Awesome? Of course... the issue (otherwise I wouldn't be here) is that the messages come in without a phone number. So I'll get:

```
1410000001 admin@work.com Sbj: This is a... MSG: This is a message
1410000002 admin@work.com Sbj: This is a... MSG: This is a message
1410000003 admin@work.com Sbj: This is a... MSG: This is a message
1410000004 admin@work.com Sbj: This is a... MSG: This is a message
1410000005 admin@work.com Sbj: This is a... MSG: This is a message
...
1410000756 admin@work.com Sbj: This is a... MSG: This is a message
```

Each message comes across as a new user. The numbers do seem to reset periodically but I've always just deleted them.

I'd like to create a contact, and "push" these messages to that user. I wouldn't mind being able to "clean" up some of the static fluff in the message as well (Getting rid of the "header" crap and just saving what's after the "MSG: " part.

I'm a baby programmer, so I may have to break down and make this myself... but is there something out there already taht might do what I'm looking for already?

Comment: Is it possible to ask your IT department to put the phone number into the sms system? That maybe the easiest solution.

Comment: I haven't looked into that side of if, and it may be a solution... but it's a pretty rinkdink program, and I don't have faith in how customize-able it is.

Comment: I deal will a few of them before. You don't even need to put a real number, anything within 10 digits go. It is like putting in the local fax number of your fax machine.

Comment: Do they always start with `admin@work.com`? If so, I might have a solution.

Comment: The layout of all of them is the same. Haven't seen anything customization in the sending program, so I was tinkering with the SDK to build a custom app to regex->user them. Just haven't gotten far at all lol